# Storing characters in MATLAB arrays

Tags: matlab

I want to store a character along with numbers ? Is using Cells the only way ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, unless you store the ASCII values but I don't think it would be very useful.

Edit: Or an array of structures?

```
a.num = [1 2 3]
a.char = 'A'
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve…

Comment: How would you know what was ascii and what was a number then, that is wrong.

Comment: *Left as an exercise to the reader* doesn't mean *wrong*. Of course you would need to know which is which. Depending on the application, one might simply *know* which indices correspond to ascii values, or one could keep a logical array to use as a mask, or something else…

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic Computer Science 101 sort of question. An array holds 1 type of data traditionally. In matlab the term gets abused.

Here are some things to know:

- An array of characters is called a string
- An array can only store one data type
- The size of an array can’t change

But matlab has an abstraction on top of all this so the engineer that didn't study programming for a year can still get the job done. Whilst matlab lets you change the size of a 1D matrix, it still won't let you have different types of data in the same array. Keep in mind that matlab 1D arrays aren't strictly arrays because this fact. Similarly with arrays of arrays with differing in size. Matlab doesn’t allow different data structures for optimization reasons.
This question arises from not knowing the containers which are available.

- List: A container indexed elements (great for sorting and adding elements quickly)
- Set: for a collection of unique elements (great for ensuring that there are no duplicates)
- Map: Great for quickly retrieving elements based on a unique identifier
  Java has implementations for these and you can use these within matlab if you want which is the general way it is done if you need a collection other than a matrix. I don’t think matlab bothered to wrap these classes themselves because they would be exactly the same anway.

In general its not a great idea to store different data types in these collections if you can avoid it, do so but otherwise so be it.

PS I don't think structs should ever be used because there is no way to know what members they have without debugging them.

If you do

```
a.num = [1 2 3]
a.char = 'A'
```

Unless you tell everyone a.num and a.char exist there is no way of knowing that a has char and num, without running code. Bad bad practice.